# Number of positive integral solution of product $x_{1} \cdot x_{2} \cdot x_{3}\cdot x_{4}\cdot x_{5}=1050$ is

Tags: combinatorics

The number of positive integral solution of product $x_{1} \cdot x_{2} \cdot x_{3}\cdot x_{4}\cdot  x_{5}=1050$ is

$\bf{My\; Try}::$ Given $x_{1}\cdot x_{2}\cdot x_{3}\cdot x_{4}\cdot x_{5} = 2 \times 3 \times 5^2 \times 7$.

Now Let we have $5$ Different Boxes $x_{1}\;,x_{2}\;,x_{3}\;,x_{4}\;,x_{5}$ and $5$ balls in

which prints a numbers $2\;,3\;,5\;,5\;,7$.

Now We have to put balls into boxes , So we will form different cases.

$\bullet \;$ If all the balls are in same boxes(boxes contain all balls or no balls)

Then no. of ways $ = 5\times 5 \times 5\times 5 \times 5 = 5^5$

$\bullet \; $ If all balles are in different boxes, Then no. of ways $\displaystyle  = $

Now I did not understand how can i find in $\bf{(II)}$ cases,

Help me Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $1050 = 2^1 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7^1$, each positive integer factor $x_k$, $1 \leq k \leq 5$, in the product $$1050 = x_1 \cdot x_2 \cdot x_3 \cdot x_4 \cdot x_5$$ is of the form 
$$x_k = 2^{a_k}3^{b_k}5^{c_k}7^{d_k}$$
where $a_k, b_k, c_k, d_k$ are non-negative integers satisfying the equations
\begin{align*}
a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5 & = 1 \tag{1}\\
b_1 + b_2 + b_3 + b_4 + b_5 & = 1 \tag{2}\\
c_1 + c_2 + c_3 + c_4 + c_5 & = 2 \tag{3}\\
d_1 + d_2 + d_3 + d_4 + d_5 & = 1 \tag{4}
\end{align*}
Equations 1, 2, and 4 each have five possible solutions since we must choose which of the five variables is equal to $1$.  A particular solution of equation 3 corresponds to the placement of four addition signs in a row of two ones.  For instance,
$$+ + 1 1 + +$$
corresponds to the solution $c_1 = 0$, $c_2 = 0$, $c_3 = 2$, $c_4 = 0$, $c_5 = 0$, while 
$$1 + + + 1 +$$
corresponds to the solution $c_1 = 1$, $c_2 = 0$, $c_3 = 0$, $c_4 = 1$, $c_5 = 0$.  Hence, the number of solutions of equation 3 is equal to the number of ways of placing four addition signs in a row of two ones, which is 
$$\binom{4 + 2}{4} = \binom{6}{4} = 15$$
since we must choose which four of the six symbols (two ones and four addition signs) will be addition signs.

Therefore, the number of positive integral solutions of the product $$1050 = x_1 \cdot x_2 \cdot x_3 \cdot x_4 \cdot x_5$$
is $5 \cdot 5 \cdot 15 \cdot 5 = 1875$.

Answer (score 3):

You can put $2,3,7$ in the boxes in five ways each. The fives can be placed in $5+\binom 52$ ways.

$5$ represents both of the $5$s in the same box. $\binom 52$ represents them in different boxes.

So you should get $5\times 5 \times 5 \times 15$ ways.

---

It appears that the first case in the question, where the $5$s are in the same box should give the result $5^4$ rather than $5^5$ because the pair of $5$s acts as a single unit rather than two separate units.

If the $5$s are in separate boxes, they are indistinguishable, and can be swapped without changing the factorisation. The first $5$ can be placed in any of $5$ boxes, and the second in any of the remaining $4$ boxes, but this counts every possibility twice. So the number of ways of placing the $5$s is $\cfrac {5\times 4}2=10$. This second case counts for $5^3\times 10$ possibilities.

The number of ways of choosing $r$ places out of a possible $n$ is so commonly encountered that it is given the (modern) symbol $\binom nr=\frac {n!}{r!(n-r)!}$. Apologies if this confused you, but it is useful to know, as you are likely to encounter it frequently, especially if you ask similar questions on this site.

Comment: I thought the exact same thing, but those solutions are not all essentially different. Many times you get the same five factors with their order interchanged ... One could divide by $5!$, but that would be wrong, since if two or more factors are equal it will not matter interchanging them.

Comment: @String you didn't say that different orders were to count as the same factorisation. In fact the method of calculation in the question suggested otherwise.

Comment: I do not know if they do. We must ask the OP about that.

Comment: Thanks friends actually answer given for $\bf{(I)}$ case is $\displaystyle = 5^4$ and for $\bf{(II)}$ case is $\displaystyle = 5^3 \cdot \frac{4}{2}$. So Total is $\displaystyle 3 \cdot 5^4$

Comment: To Mark Bennet, would you like to explain me in detail, Actually I did not understand yours solution,Thanks

Comment: @juantheron I have added a bit more to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Better way,

Every number can be expressed as a product of powers of prime.

So,
let $x_1=2^{a_1}*3^{b_1}$ and so on $x_2=2^{a_2} *3^{b_2}$ and so on..

so u get $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5=$(power of 2 in 1050) and 
$b_1+b2+b3+b4+b5=$(power of 3 in 1050).
You know the number of ways for each.

Get the number of ways for each such set of prime and multiply all of them to get your answer.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score -1):

Each box can contain $5$ elements so it will be toatal $5^5$ cases I think.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.  Since $1050 = 2^1 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7^1$, each factor is of the form $$x_k = 2^{a_k}3^{b_k}5^{c_k}7^{d_k}$$ where we have the constraints \begin{align*} a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5 & = 1\\ b_1 + b_2 + b_3 + b_4 + b_5 & = 1\\ c_1 + c_2 + c_3 + c_4 + c_5 & = 2\\ d_1 + d_2 + d_3 + d_4 + d_5 & = 1 \end{align*}